# styled components - passing props to GlobalStyle

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have **GlobalStyle** with some overwrites like:

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  h6 {
    font-weight: ${props => (props.semibold ? 600 : "bold")};
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  ...
`;
```

I would like to pass props from my components to GlobalStyle for eg. weight. Something like this (from JSX):

```
const LocalComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h6 semibold>This should be semi-bold text</h6>
    </div>
  );
};
```

above example doesn't work ofc. But is there a way to achieve this?
Currently I'm wrapping **h6** into another SC, and adding font-weight locally. It would be much better to have it on global scale without need to create another component just as a wrapper for bold text etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if it is what you really need, but you can try.

I needed to change my font-family according to language from i18next, and wanted to forward a prop to GlobalStyle, but didn't find a direct way.

Then, I tried to send a "lang" property to the ThemeProvider to make is accessible from the props object in styled, and it has worked:

```
<ThemeProvider 
   theme={{ 
           ...theme, 
           lang: i18n.language 
          }}>
   <RouterProvider router={router} />
   <GlobalStyle />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Then I access the 'lang' in GlobalStyle:

```
body {
    font-family: ${(props) => {
      switch (props.theme.lang) {
        case 'en':
          return 'Mulish, sans-serif';
        default:
          return 'Outfit, sans-serif';
      }
    }};
    
}
```

I'm not sure if it is the best solution, but it works though.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the above information, it isn't clear what part is missing.

I am presuming you have added the `<ThemeProvider theme={your_theme} />` as a wrapper around your application (e.g. `<App />`) This will inject props into all of your styled-components if they are children of `<App />`.

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={your_theme}>
     <GlobalStyle />
     <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
```

Don't forget to add your `<GlobalStyle />` component as a child to the ThemeProvider, or the props will not populate.